# Magento 2 - How to config mail sending?

Tags: magento2, email, system-config

In Magento 2, How to config mail sending ? I used the gmail host to test. I set below but I try use feature forgot password on front-end and then I can't see email in client's mail box.
[image]

View "**forgot password**"
[image]

Comment: To send email using Gmail SMTP server you need to either (1) reconfigure your server to send email through Gmail or (2) install a third-party extension. eg  https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmail-smtp-app

Comment: magepal smtp extension works great!

Answer (score 5):

Mailing in Magento 2 isn't sent by SMTP by default, it uses `mail` PHP function. To use SMTP you have to install extension, ie. [Extension1 (paid)](https://amasty.com/smtp-email-settings-for-magento-2.html) or [Extension2 (free)](http://store.emizentech.com/magento-2/custom-smtp.html)

You can also write your own module to do so ([like in this tutorial](http://webkul.com/blog/magento-2-send-mail-using-your-smtp-detail/)) :)

Answer (score 5):

Without adding an extention, the best way is to add and configure PostFix for Gmail account (Tested on Mac & Linux):

### SASL Authentication

Connecting to the Gmail SMTP server requires both SSL and authentication. To set up authentication you will need to edit the /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd file.

`sudo vim /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`

Update the contents to include the following. Note that enclosing hostnames with square brackets – [] – tells Postfix to avoid doing an MX lookup. Make sure to replace EMAIL with your email address, and PASSWORD with your Gmail password, properly escaping any colons in it.

`[smtp.gmail.com]:587 EMAIL@gmail.com:PASSWORD`

Use the postmap command to update the SASL credentials in Postfix :

`sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`

### Postfix Relay Configuration

Next we need to edit the Postfix configuration found in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

`sudo vim /etc/postfix/main.cf`

I was not able to route mail to the Gmail SMTP servers over IPv6, so force only IPv4 connections by searching for the inet_protocols key and updating the value.

`inet_protocols = ipv4`

If any of the following keys already exist in your configuration comment them out, and include the following at the bottom of the config file.

### Gmail SMTP relay

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587

# Enable SASL authentication in the Postfix SMTP client.
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = AUTH LOGIN

# Enable Transport Layer Security (TLS), i.e. SSL.
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

### Restart Postfix & Test

Restart Postfix as root, then send a test email.

```
sudo postfix stop && sudo postfix start
date | mail -s "Test Email" YOUR_EMAIL@gmail.com
```

Comment: I have the exact same config but when i send magento order email it says mailq is empty. the mail function sends email but magento does not use postfix

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 send via **PHP Email** by default.
If you want to use Gmail to send email, you should try to install Custom SMTP module. I found this [SMTP module on Github](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp) - Yes, Free :)

Hmm, a screenshot:

[image: smtp configuration]

User guide: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp#user-guide

Answer (score 0):

For Sending Mail, you need to install and configure SMTP extension.

**Extension link:** https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/

**Configuration link**: https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/how-to-configure-mailcom-smtp-in-magento-2.html