# Magento 2: How to solve the message "Unable to send email"?

Tags: magento2, email, newsletter

My Magento 2 send an email when I register in the newsletter, but I receive that exception all time:

[image]

How can I solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To send email from Magento you need to configure an email SMTP server on the web host/server. Magento uses the PHP [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) method by default, although there are extensions you can install to override this behavior.

If it's JUST the Newsletter that's not sending, and other emails like Registration and Password Reset are sending fine, then it could be some other problem and you will need to post more information.

It could be a PHP ini configuration issue with the `mail` function, like a bad path to `sendmail`, or an incorrect hostname, etc.

But as a Magento Certified Developer I assume you already know all of this? Sorry if I misunderstood your question and gave too many obvious answers.

Related posts:

- [Magento 2 - How to config mail sending?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115248/magento-2-how-to-config-mail-sending)
- [Magento 2: How to send emails from localhost?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141977/how-to-send-emails-from-localhost-in-magento-2-1)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912992/php-mail-does-not-get-sent-how-do-i-debug
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896280/debugging-php-mail-and-or-phpmailer

Comment: Make sense, but my sendmail is configured as your links. It's working but my mail function returns false after sending the email.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2.3.1 check out this bug:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/20033