# Magento 2 Unable to Send Mail

Tags: magento2, email, third-party-module

How would solve this? Magento is unable to send mail.
I am on a localhost and have the Mageplaza SMTP module installed.

[image]

Here is an excerpt  my controller code. the $to and $from emails are actual emails (just changed it for this post)

```
$postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
$postObject->setData($post);

$storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

$userSubject='test mail';

$from = [
    'name' => 'sample',
    'email' => 'from@gmail.com',
];

$to = [
    'email' => 'to@gmail.com',
    'name' => 'stuff',
];

$template = "course_request";
$transport = $this->_transportBuilder
    ->setTemplateIdentifier($template) // email template
    ->setTemplateOptions( [
        'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,  \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE
        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
    ])
    ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
    ->setFrom($from, $storeScope)
    ->addTo($to, $storeScope)
    ->getTransport();
$transport->sendMessage();

$this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Email was succesfully sent!'));
```

I am a little new to Magento and it would help if you can explain a little. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please review this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/180798 I hope it will work for you

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm on localhost rather than on a server. I have also read that post and sadly it has not been helpful.