# Magento 2.3 unable to send email server configuration

Tags: magento2, error, email

I am using Magento 2.3 , I try to send a mail but unfortunately, I am not able to send any mail I got error

> Unable to send mail: Unknown error at
>   /home/public_html/proj/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php:305)"}
>   []

then **I am using Hostgator Server is there anything configured from server side** because I tried **mageplaza smtp** module it says mail sent successfully but I didn't get any mail

how do i fix this ?

Comment: are you using custom code to send an email ?

Comment: No custom code ...

Comment: make sure you have correctly configured sender email. may I know for which action are you trying to get an email.

Comment: I check reset password only. in configuration, I added mymail@gmail.com

Comment: please refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115248/magento-2-how-to-config-mail-sending may it will help you

Comment: Are you using dadicated server or shared server?

Comment: i think dedicated server

Comment: Have you checked your server mail log? Since  mageplaza smtp says mail sent successfully checking maillog will give an exact idea. You can find it in /var/log/maillog

Comment: Have you tried Gmail SMTP server to send emails, you can configure it in mageplaza SMTP. If the mail is sent, try using free SMTP servers likes Sendgrid etc.